# How to explode StructType to rows from json dataframe in Spark rather than to columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read a nested json with this schema :

```
 root
 |-- company: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 10: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 100: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 101: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 102: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 103: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 104: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 105: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 106: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 107: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 108: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 109: string (nullable = true)
```

When I try to :

```
df.select(col("company.*"))
```

I get every fields of the struct "company" as columns. But I want them as rows. I would like to get a row with the id and the string in another column :

```
  0        1         10       100      101        102 
"hey"   "yooyo"    "yuyu"    "hey"   "yooyo"    "yuyu"
```

But rather get something like :

```
id    name
0     "hey"
1     "yoooyo"
10    "yuuy"
100   "hey"
101   "yooyo"
102    "yuyu"
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Tricky

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this using union:

```
val dfExpl = df.select("company.*")

dfExpl.columns
.map(name => dfExpl.select(lit(name),col(name)))
  .reduce(_ union _)
  .show
```

Or alternatively using array/explode :

```
val dfExpl = df.select("company.*")
val selectExpr = dfExpl
  .columns
  .map(name =>
    struct(
      lit(name).as("id"),
      col(name).as("value")
    ).as("col")
  )


dfExpl
  .select(
    explode(array(selectExpr: _*))
  )
  .select("col.*")
  .show()
```

Comment: Dunno about the others, but your second solution is really faster for my use case. Thanks for the two solutions, is it because explode is optimized for this kind of operation ?

Comment: make sure to `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode,lit,struct,array,col}`

Comment: Is there a pyspark version of this answer?